# Can I use Goroutines in Google App Engine (Standard Environment)?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The following example seems to work, but is it safe to use? My goal is to do some very light background processing (whereas an actual task queue job feels too heavy).

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  go func() {
    // do something ...
  }() 

  return // 200
}
```

Comment: This thread is probably of interest: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/fv1BgRHcH_M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goroutines that *outlive* the request are not supported, but you can use [runtime.RunInBackground](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime#background_requests) to execute code in a background goroutine:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  err := runtime.RunInBackground(c, func(c appengine.Context) {
    // do something...
  })

  return // 200
}
```

The provided function will be invoked with a background context that is distinct from (and may outlast) the provided context. Note that there is a limit of 10 simultaneous background requests per instance. Here is [another example](https://talks.golang.org/2013/highperf.slide#25).

Please note that Goroutines that *live within the context* of a request, are supported though:

> The Go runtime environment for App Engine provides full support for
>   goroutines, but not for parallel execution: goroutines are scheduled
>   onto a single operating system thread. This single-thread restriction
>   may be lifted in future versions. Multiple requests may be handled
>   concurrently by a given instance; that means that if one request is,
>   say, waiting for a datastore API call, another request may be
>   processed by the same instance. ([Source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime#Go_Introduction))

Comment: According to [this](https://talks.golang.org/2013/highperf.slide#25) what you are saying seems to be wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use goroutines. For access to appengine services you need background context, (still) available via call of appengine.RunInBackground.

Comment: @divan what will be the approach to do this after migrating to go112 on google appengine ?