# How to use goroutine inside AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goroutine

I'm using Cloud Endpoints and Go and I'm trying to call a method in asynchronous way by using a goroutine.

When I'm running the following code locally I can see the debug prints but on the server it looks like the method did not get called.

I'm basically trying to do

```
go doStuff()

return type
```

Comment: Are you able to provide any more details about your code?  According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/), *"The Go runtime environment for App Engine provides full support for goroutines, but not for parallel execution"*. It's not clear from the docs, but a [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/managed-vms/) may not have the same restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go runtime for AppEngine supports goroutines, quoting from the doc: [Go Runtime Environment: Introduction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/runtime):

> The Go runtime environment for App Engine provides full support for goroutines, but not for parallel execution: goroutines are scheduled onto a single operating system thread.

The problem is that when your [`HandleFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) or [`Handler.ServeHTTP()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) returns, the AppEngine platform (and the [`http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package too) **does not wait** for any goroutines started by the handler function to complete.

Quoting from the doc: [Handling Requests: Responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/requests#Go_Responses):

> App Engine calls the handler with a `Request` and a `ResponseWriter`, then waits for the handler to write to the `ResponseWriter` and return. When the handler returns, the data in the `ResponseWriter`'s internal buffer is sent to the user.

You have to synchronize your request handling and goroutine, and only return once the goroutine has completed its work, for example:

```
func doStuff(done chan int) {
    // Do your stuff
    // and finally signal that you're done:
    done <- 0
}

func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    done := make(chan int)
    go doStuff(done)
    // Wait for the goroutine to complete:
    <-done
}
```

Comment: so basically i have to block the goroutine ?
what can i do to avoid the blocking

Comment: @MIkCode No, you have to block the request handler until the goroutine is finished (not the other way around). When the request handler returns, that's the end.

Comment: im just wondering if their  any option to return the user a response before the  goroutine end ?

Comment: @MIkCode The goroutine is not stopped or anything when the request handler returns. The goroutine may continue to run even after the handler returned, but the goroutine can't do any request related tasks after that (would either result in an error or would have no effect).

Comment: @MIkCode And also note that AppEngine does not send any data back to the client until the request handler returns. Data written by the request handler is first written into a buffer, and data is only sent to the user after the handler returned.

Comment: @MIkCode I'm trying to do same stuff here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967066/publishing-to-google-pub-sub-asynchronously-through-goroutine
Tried this approach as well but not able to do that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185405/can-i-use-goroutines-in-google-app-engine-standard-environment
can you tell how you solve this problem